# Provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. Can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, paginator, mat-pagination

I have been trying to implement **server side pagination** using **mat-paginator** & have faced a lot of difficulties. I've checked various blogs & tutorials but none of them helped me much to achieve my goal.

**Service-**

```
getAllCategoryByPage(data?: any): Observable<any> {
    var Url = `/Categories/GetAll`;
    return this.http
      .post<any>(Url, data)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<any>('getAllCategoryByPage', [])));
  }
```

**Components .ts-**

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort; //sorting is not mandatory in my case
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadCategoryList;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadCategoryList();
     this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
loadCategoryList = (): void => {
    this.paginator.page.subscribe((resp) => {console.log(resp);});    
    merge(this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.asyncService.start();
          console.log(this.paginator.pageIndex ,this.paginator.pageSize);
          return this.categoryService.getAllCategoryByPage(
            {
              "page": this.paginator.pageIndex + 1,
              "pageSize": this.paginator.pageSize,
              "searchString": ""
            }
          )
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data.apiData);
          this.length = data.totalRecord;
          this.dataSource.paginator = data.apiData;
          this.asyncService.finish();
        }
      );
  };
```

**Html-**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="sl">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> SL. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;"> {{i+1}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >CATEGORY NAME </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.categoryName}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >STATUS </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
         {{element.recStatus}}
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ACTIONS</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" >
          <button class="table-button-action" style="color: red;" (click)="deleteRow(row)" >
            <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button class="table-button-action" style="color:royalblue;" (click)="onEdit(row)">
            <mat-icon>create</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [length]= "length" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
    </mat-paginator>
```

I am **not getting the data** in the table. Here, I'm getting error when the page is **loaded** as well as when I am **navigating** through the pages (using next & previous buttons) which I've no clue for what the error is occurring & how to solve it

Can anyone please guide me to **fix** it so it works perfectly?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is not a proper use of bold font...also it is more confusing than helpful

Comment: I suspect the problem is with `merge()` you are calling it in `ngOnInit` when `paginator` has no value...you should add a check before that to see if `paginator` actually has a value

Comment: @MrCodingB Can you please elaborate how to do that? I'm not understanding...

Comment: Before you call `merge()` you should place an if statement like this one `if (!this.paginator) { return; }`. So in case the paginator isn't set it doesn't merge

Comment: Could you please include the content of `this.categoryService.getAllCategoryByPage` function here?

Comment: @MrCodingB  shows same error even after putting condition :(

Comment: You should provide stackblitz to debug. Or at least full error code with descirption.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the service function `getAllCategoryByPage`, doesn't return a proper `Observable`, and I expect that happens because the `catchError` isn't properly (you passed the function directly within it, without returning an observable).

So could you please try the following:

```js
getAllCategoryByPage(data?: any): Observable<any> {
    var Url = `/Categories/GetAll`;
    return this.http.post<any>(Url, data).pipe(
        catchError(() => {
            this.handleError<any>('getAllCategoryByPage', []);
            return EMPTY;
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Still showing the same error :( Also data is not loaded in the table...

Comment: Could you please [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) it?

Answer (score 0):

In your `subscribe` handler you have this:

```
this.dataSource.paginator = data.apiData;
```

You should assign the data to `this.dataSource.data` property instead.
Try this:

```
this.dataSource.data = data.apiData;
```

Comment: Previously, it was `this.dataSource.data = data.apiData;` But in that case the navigation buttons didn't work properly. So, I changed it into `this.dataSource.paginator = data.apiData;`

Comment: You should take a closer look to the [examples in the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-overview). You can notice that the data needs to be assigned to dataSource.data, or you can also do it with dataSource.setData method.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same situation. The problem was in dependency injection when my module which provided CustomDatePickerIntl wrongly.
The solution was to change:
from:
`{ provide: MatDatepickerIntl, useValue: CustomMatDatePickerIntl }`

to:
`{ provide: MatDatepickerIntl, useClass: CustomMatDatePickerIntl }`

Check if there are no wrong object properties like useValue instead of proper useClass.